# type declaration of arrays

Tags: common-lisp

I've a very big array composed of only `nil` s and `t` s .

My questions is; does it make sense for the compiler to make type declaration within a function that handles this specific type of array. If so what should the declaration look like?

For example:

```
(defun foo(my-array)
     (declare (type (array ?????) my-array))
      ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that in Common Lisp an array of type `(array boolean)` (where [BOOLEAN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_ban.htm) is the applicable type) is not an array that just happens to contain only `t`s and `nil`s, but an array that can only contain those, which is a property that has to be specified during creation of the array. Violating this will result in a run-time error or undefined behaviour depending on your `safety` level.

I don't think there is much point in specifying the type at function level, since I don't believe there are any applicable optimizations. You might consider using [bit-vectors](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_bt_vec.htm), which are at least tightly packed and allow the use of fast bit processing instructions. That is, if your data is representable in one dimension, since I am not sure how much those apply for multidimensional `(array bit)` arrays.

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays with type '(mod 2) work fine as multi-dimensional bit arrays.